# Empty query on Custom Post Type, using WP_Query or get_posts

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I've searched in SE and on Internet for 2 days without success.

The problem is: I've a function that runs on "save_post_eventi" hook in WP backend dashboard, that starts with a simple query:

```
mk_delete_itself_from_other_events{
$params = array(
                'post_type'     =>  'eventi',
                'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
                'post_status'   =>  'publish'
             );
$all_posts = get_posts($params);
}
```

and it returns an empty array, like this (var_export):

```
array (  0 => false,)
```

or this, if I use WP_Query instead of get_posts

```
(object) array(   'scalar' => false,)
```

The CPT is populated, is public and has this settings:

```
register_post_type('eventi', array(
'label' => 'Eventi',
'description' => '',
'hierarchical' => false,
'supports' => array(
    0 => 'title',
    1 => 'editor',
    2 => 'thumbnail',
    3 => 'custom-fields',
    4 => 'revisions',
    5 => 'page-attributes',
),
'taxonomies' => array(
    0 => 'categoria-evento',
    1 => 'pubblico',
    2 => 'tipologia-evento',
),
'public' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'delete_with_user' => 'null',
'labels' => array(
),
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'show_in_rest' => true,
'rest_base' => '',
'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
'acfe_archive_template' => '',
'acfe_archive_ppp' => 10,
'acfe_archive_orderby' => 'date',
'acfe_archive_order' => 'DESC',
'acfe_single_template' => '',
'acfe_admin_archive' => false,
'acfe_admin_ppp' => 10,
'acfe_admin_orderby' => 'date',
'acfe_admin_order' => 'DESC',
'menu_position' => 5,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'capabilities' => array(
),
'map_meta_cap' => NULL,));
```

If I use "post" instead of "eventi", the query works, of course.

This is how I hook the function (currently, the function itself is empty, I'm just trying to get the posts!); that function triggers whenever I update a post using quick edit (this is the intended behaviour).

```
add_action('save_post_eventi', 'mk_delete_itself_from_other_events', 10);
```

What I've tried so far:

1. disable all plugins
2. switched hosts (from apache/nginx to litespeed)
3. changed PHP versions
4. changed hook (save_posts, acf/save_post); this changed the context, so the function run inside Gutenberg, or in dashboard; In any case, nothing changes.
5. changed priority (5,10,20); this changes when it runs, before save or after save post. Nothing changes.

I'm out of ideas, there's something I'm missing?
Thanks for any direction :)

Comment: Are there any posts of type eventi created and with a published status?

Comment: yes, there are many. 49 published (public), and some drafts.

Comment: Post the code you're using to hook onto `save_post_{$post->post_type}`, as i see no reason anything above shouldn't function. Equivalent test code for a custom type works as expected locally using that hook..

Comment: I've edited my question, adding the hook. Thanks!

Comment: Either you've missed out a chunk of your function, or it's an invalid function and likely to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I've disabled everything, leaving only WP, ACF and this function, and nothing changes.
I've 3 CPT on my site, and another one has the same behaviour.
I've compared the CPT's and all have the same settings (like the one posted above).
I'm really clueless :(